# Is making table for each location a good approach for weather parameter?

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to design a database for my project and I am confused and tried to make individual table for each location or station with parameter like date, rainfall,temp.

Comment: No need to have a individual table for each location. Have one table with columns location, date,rainfall and temp. Make location and date as primary key if you insert data only once per day